# Can I construct jQuery ready function so VS can recognize its name

Tags: visual-studio, document-ready

In Visual Studio when I writing large js files a lager help is top drop'n down menu for navigation to functions and other objects.

When I declare jQuery ready function like

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

Then there is no name for that function in top menu.

I wondering can I construct jQuery function some how different to vs recognize its name.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no name displayed because you didn't give one to the function (it's [anonymous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)), which is perfectly OK here).

If you want to have a name in the dropdown, add one like this:

```
$(document).ready(function onReady() { ... })
```

In this case, `onReady` will show up in the dropdown.